# Foreach do something after x times?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, count

I'm trying to create an automatic block with links [ They come from an array ], 
everything went well before I had too much links, Now they're all on the same line,
How can I make foreach print br  after 4 times?

now it's like this:

```
foreach($this->rpanelinks as $name => $url) {
    echo '<a href="' . BASE_URL . $url . '">' . $name . '</a>';
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a counter:

```
$i = 1;

foreach($this->rpanelinks as $name => $url) {
    if($i == 4) 
        echo '<br>';

    echo '<a href="' . BASE_URL . $url . '">' . $name . '</a>';

    ++$i;
}
```

or if you wan't **every** 4 times

```
$i = 1;

foreach($this->rpanelinks as $name => $url) {
    if($i % 4 == 0) 
         echo '<br>';

    echo '<a href="' . BASE_URL . $url . '">' . $name . '</a>';

    ++$i;
}
```

`$i % 4` calculates the rest of the operation `$i / 4` and if it's `0` the value uf `$i` is dividable by `4`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question much to be honest. However, you can put whatever logic to your foreach you want. For example:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($this->rpanelinks as $name => $url) {
    $counter ++;
    echo '<a href="' . BASE_URL . $url . '">' . $name . '</a>';
    if ($counter %4 == 0) echo '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;

foreach($this->rpanelinks as $name => $url) {
    ++$i;
    if($i >= 4){
        echo '<br/>';
        $i=0;
    }
    echo '<a href="' . BASE_URL . $url . '">' . $name . '</a>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use variable to count your links, following code prints `breakline` after each 4 links

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($this->rpanelinks as $name => $url) {
    echo '<a href="' . BASE_URL . $url . '">' . $name . '</a>';
    if(++$counter % 4 == 0) {
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```